# Можно ли себе на комп сохранить панорамы 360 с гугл карт?

Tags: google-maps

Т. е. чтобы можно было смотреть улицы оффлайн.

Answer (score 1):

Есть программа SAS Planet - она сохраняет локально открываемые тобой карты (в том числе спутник, но про панорамы не уверен, давно не пользовался). Т. е. первый раз просматриваешь с интернетом, а потом те же самые картинки берутся из локального кэша. Вроде бы бы была портативная версия.

Скачать всё полностью не получится, поскольку там огромный объём и даже просто хранить на компьютере такой объём данных (фото по всей планете) не выйдет. По автоматизации скачивания в пределах города или района лично мне ничего не известно.

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно используя Google Earth Pro ([скачать на русском](https://www.google.com.ua/intl/ru/earth/download/gep/agree.html)).

Там можно выбрать панораму и она закешируется на вашем компьютере.

Кроме того, существует аналог под Андроид и iOS, а также дополнение к Chrome с похожим функционалом.

[Информация о версиях](https://www.google.com/intl/ru/earth/versions/)

Comment: Скачал эту программу. И на сколько я понял, те панорамы, которые я просмотрел будут где-то временно сохраняться? А где именно?

Comment: Скорее всего в %AppData% либо %LocalAppData%. Дело в том, что формат который использует Гугл вероятнее всего непонятен другим программам. Ищите там, но если нужно просто оффлайн просмотр, то Гугл предлагает смотреть через приложение Планета.

Comment: Речь идёт о приложении "Планета", ссылку на которую вы дали в первом ответе? Так я её скачал и пытался найти кнопку сохранения или воспроизведения просмотренных мной панорам. Т. е. просмотренные панорамы нужно как-то самому сохранять для дальнейшего оффлайн просмотра или они сами сохраняются, а в таком случае где они сохраняются? Мне нужно именно иметь возможность просмотра улиц оффлайн.

Comment: У Google свой формат для хранения этих данных. Скачивание не было в доступных вариантах, если вы хотите смотреть - смотрите через приложение даже офлайн. Уверен, что никто исходные файлы в открытом виде не будет хранить.